# robotframework doesn't see the xpath

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a problem for these elements (adresse email and mot de passe please look the picture)
I explain I take the xpath for these eleemnts in website 
after in variables I create locator like this

```
pages_elements.add(name="emailcpte"           , type="element",        locator='//*[@id="autofill-form"]/screen-register/p[3]/input')
pages_elements.add(name="mdpcpte"             , type="element",        locator='//*[@id="autofill-form"]/screen-register/p[4]/input')
```

but when I run the test case I have always the same error:

```
Element '//*[@id="autofill-form"]/screen-register/p[4]/input' not visible after 10 seconds."
```

I don't understand why 
please can you help me ?

I don't use python and roboframework since long time maybe its a stupid or easy question, if it is the case sorry

My env:

```
Python 3.7.0
robotframework_ride-1.7.3.1
robotframework-3.1.2
```

[image: Elements]

Comment: Is the element inside an iframe?

Comment: no the elements are not  in iframe

Comment: I don't know: is RobotFramework running JavaScript on page? If page uses JavaScript to add element and RobotFramework doesn't run JavaScript then it can be your problem.

Comment: ok it's possible Do you have one solution please ?

Comment: use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can uses  JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Oakley you right 
element inside an iframe sorry 
Just need to select the iframe after xpath are ok